# latexmk: interaction=nonstopmode not effective

Tags: latexmk

I have this sample LaTeX file and I am using `latexmk -f -interaction=nonstopmode -latex Eqn.tex` and the nonstopmode is not effective. I understand the actual issue in the equation. My question is how do I make the engine to pass and show the error only in the log file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\begin{document}

$$\begin{aligned} Q - Q' = {\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} [ -2^j]P &{} \text {if } k_j = 0,\\  [2^j]P &{} \text {if } k_j = 1. \end{array}\right. } \end{aligned}$$

\end{document}
```

Log

```
...
entering extended mode
^C! Interruption.
<to be read again>
                   \vskip
l.7 ... [ -2^j]P &{} \text {if } k_j = 0,\\  [2^j]
                                                  P &{} \text {if } k_j = 1....

? x
No pages of output.
```

It just wait for some input from the user.

Comment: nonstopmode still scrolls messages to the terminal, perhaps you look for batchmode ?

Comment: In batchmode, it waits for user input as well.

Comment: ah not waiting for input, looping I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you scroll past an error (in batchmode or nonstopmode) tex will try to recover without any user interaction however if you program a loop, either explicitly or as a result of unfortunate error recovery, there will be no error prompt but TeX may just hang as it loops.

If you run the provided example interactively you get 8 errors but then no more error prompts as TeX is in a tight loop, if you hit Ctrl-C to interupt it you see

```
! Interruption.
<to be read again> 
                   \vskip 
l.7 ... [ -2^j]P &{} \text {if } k_j = 0,\\  [2^j]
                                                  P &{} \text {if } k_j = 1....

?
```

Which shows that the document is now equivalent to

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\let\par\relax
zzz\vskip 5pt

\end{document}
```

This will loop forever with no error until interupted.

TeX sees the `\vskip` in horizontal mode so adds `\par` to end the paragraph then executes a re-inserted `\vskip`, but `\par` has been redefined to do nothing so the `\vskip` is again seen in hmode and it loops.  As there is no error here `--interaction` has no effect.

Comment: Adding `texfot` before the latexmk command worked out well. `texfot latexmk -f -latex Eqn.tex`.

Comment: @Dominic I don't think texfot will help here (and doesn't when I try it) `texfot latexmk -f -latex Eqn.tex` avoids the loop as you are not using `nonstopmode` so stop at the first error, not because of `texfot`.